# Getting count value per minute in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Based on the code below I would like help to figure out a way with which the max_concrncy count can be calculated on a minute basis. The query at present returns the count on a daily basis and I am having difficulty trying to get a minute based count.

```
SELECT cast(to_char(date,'MM-DD-YYYY') as date) log_dt ,initcap(url),
url,count(userid) tot_hits,count(distinct userid) unq_hits,
count (cast(to_char(date,'MM-01-YYYY hh:mi:00') as date))as max_concrncy 
**// i need max of count (cast(to_char(date,'MM-01-YYYY hh:mi:00') as date)) as max_concrncy here**

,case when httpstatuscode>=100 and httpstatuscode<=199 then httpstatuscode
    else null end as sts_cd_100 
,case when httpstatuscode>=200 and httpstatuscode<=299 then httpstatuscode
    else null end as sts_cd_200
,case when httpstatuscode>=300 and httpstatuscode<=399 then httpstatuscode
    else null end as sts_cd_300
,case when httpstatuscode>=400 and httpstatuscode<=499 then httpstatuscode else null end  as sts_cd_400
,case when httpstatuscode>=500 and httpstatuscode<=599 then httpstatuscode
    else null end as sts_cd_500
FROM sp01.apps_log_temp where initcap(url)='/766/sigma/data.Ashx'
and userid <> '-' group by cast(to_char(date,'MM-DD-YYYY') as date),httpstatuscode
```

Here is the output that the query returns. The highlighted data is the max_concrncy value which should actually be 25 and 14 which I figured out when grouping the value by minute.

```
  date             url            tothit unqhit    max_concrncy  httpstatuscode
2014-01-31  /766/sigma/data.Ashx    75  2   **75**          200
2014-01-30  /766/sigma/data.Ashx    50  1   **50**          200
```

Adding input data.

```
    date           httpstatuscode     url
2014-01-31 00:01:51   200       /766/sigma/data.ashx
2014-01-31 00:01:52   200       /766/sigma/data.ashx
2014-01-31 00:01:52   400       /766/sigma/data.ashx
2014-01-31 00:25:57   200       /766/sigma/data.ashx
2014-01-30 00:01:51   300       /766/sigma/data.ashx
2014-01-30 00:01:52   200       /766/sigma/data.ashx
2014-01-30 00:01:52   200       /766/sigma/data.ashx
2014-01-30 00:25:57   200       /766/sigma/data.ashx
```

Sorry the question is this long. Thanks for your response.

Comment: is it possible to simplify your question (I think you can remove some columns which are just adding noise) and give some example data input?

Answer (score 0):

Try date_trunc [see postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

Then you don't have to cast or do the to_char.